# Vetor: Cadastrar 5 nomes e suas alturas, depois mostrar todos em ordem crescente.

Tags: java, array

Preciso Cadastrar 5 nomes e suas alturas, depois mostrar todos em ordem crescente. O problema é que só consigo colocar as alturas na ordem, os nomes ficam na ordem que eu digitei. E também não estou conseguindo usar o double no lugar do int para a altura, pois da erro.
Segue meu código: se tiver algo muito errado, é porque ainda sou novato.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o número de pessoas a ser cadastrado "));
    String vet[] = new String[numero];
    int altura[] = new int[5];
    int aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
        vet[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome: ", null);
        altura[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a altura: ", null));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < altura.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (altura.length); j++) {
            if (altura[i] < altura[j]) {

                aux = altura[i];
                altura[i] = altura[j];
                altura[j] = aux;
            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < altura.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Nome " + (i+1) + "º " + vet[i] + altura[i] + "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado Carlos heuberger, utilizei o aux2 no código e ele funcionou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em quase todas as situações que tem várias informações associadas entre si o ideal é utilizar classes, que organizam e facilitam a lógica.

Se no seu exemplo iria cadastrar nomes e alturas, e estas referem pessoas então uma classe `Pessoa` seria uma boa ideia.

Essa classe poderia então ficar assim:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private float altura;

    public Pessoa(String nome, float altura){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public String emTexto(){
        return "Nome: " + nome + "\nAltura: " + altura;
    }
}
```

O construtor foi construído para facilitar a criação de objetos do tipo `Pessoa` logo com o `nome` e `altura`.  O método `emTexto` serve só para ter uma representação da `Pessoa` em texto e ser assim fácil de mostrar na consola.

Depois o `main` iria agora ficar diferente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o número de pessoas a ser cadastrado "));

    Pessoa pessoas[] = new Pessoa[numero]; //agora array de Pessoas

    for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.length; i++) {
        String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome: ", null);
        float altura = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a altura: ", null));

        //criar a Pessoa e inserir na posição certa do vetor
        pessoas[i] = new Pessoa(nome, altura); 
    }

    //ordena e mostra de uma só vez utilizando sorted() e forEach()
    Arrays.stream(pessoas).sorted(new Comparator<Pessoa>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) {
            return p1.getNome().compareTo(p2.getNome());
        }
    }).forEach(x-> System.out.println(x.emTexto()));
}
```

A parte de ordenação aqui como é feita com um objeto de uma classe já tem de ser personalizada, e por isso tem de receber um `Comparator`. Nesse comparador fez se a comparação das pessoas com base nos seus nomes.

Depois de feita a ordenação chamou-se o `forEach` para percorrer todas as pessoas ordenadas e mostra-las à custado método `emTexto`.

Notas:

- Para introduzir floats terá que utilizar o separador decimal de ponto.
- Para com o `Comparator` não dê erro terá que fazer o `import` correspondente: `import java.util.Comparator`;

Comment: Olá, como apontei, não estava conseguindo utilizar o double, mas com a sua dica, o float funcionou perfeitamente! Não consegui utilizar suas outras diversas linhas de código porque  não entendo muito sobre elas, mas vou analisar as novidades que ela trás para mim como forma de estudo. Obrigado pela ajuda.